# Get ACF value from custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom taxonomy "roles", which has an ACF custom post type "role_order". My understanding is that to retrieve the value I should do:

```
get_field('role_order', 'roles_222');
```

where 222 is the ID of the custom taxonomy term.

Nothing's being retrieved however. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the field name. I renamed it to "roleorder" without the underscore, and that solved the problem.